# Convention for adding partial classes to entity-first MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

What is the convention for adding partial classes to an entity-first defined model in MVC4? Or at least, how do you do it?

Edit: My specific use case comes down to having a `PowershellOperation` entity that needs to implement `Execute()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convention is not to extend entity classes. If you have PowershellOperation entity, it shouldn't contain code for its execution. I would create dedicated service layer class to handle Execute method:

```
interface IPowershellOperationService {
    Execute(int id);
}

class PowershellOperationService : IPowershellOperationService {
    ...implement execute here...
}
```

Comment: Where would I keep the code for the `PowershellOperation` if not in the entity? I have a need to persist and reuse operations

Comment: You can keep command (Powershell script) definition in entity, but code to execute it in service class. No need to keep this code in entity class.

Comment: I think I get it now... `Entity` is really not supposed to do a whole lot, right? That's why you make `ViewModel` for input models or in this case a `Service` for operation execution?

Comment: And one more question... why would you not want to include an `Entity` as a property of the service?

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos: What do you mean by property of service?

Comment: I mean why would `Execute` take an `id`? Why wouldn't the specific `PowershellOperation` entity be a member of the `PowerShellOperationService` class, ie `Execute() { this.doStuff(this.PSOperation) }`

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos: No. It shouldn't be a member. You should retrieve `PowershellOperation` from data context inside service method. Controller doesn't have to know `PowershellOperation` class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31050/discussion-between-lukled-and-tacos-tacos-tacos)